# Sliding-rightward input box with CSS

Tags: css

Is there any way to make an input box span the distance between the *right* edge of its parent and go as far left as it needs to?

What I mean is, suppose I have

```
<div>
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
    ...
    <input />
</div>
```

I'd like to make the `input` change width, so that if there were no `span`s, the `input` would stretch across the whole `div`, but if there are spans it would contract from the left?  I'd be adding the `span`s from javascript.

Is it possible to do this in pure CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, technically.

To do it with CSS only, you will need to use the new flexbox model.

However, support is [not great](http://caniuse.com/flexbox).

```
div {
  width: 30em;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

input {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kH6kU/) in Chrome.

For support in other browsers that don't support the candidate recommendation, a little bit of Javascript to add percentage based widths based on the number of spans is your best bet.